# Reduzir e simplificar query sql (mysql) redundante para relatório financeiro (hierarquia de contas)

Tags: mysql, sql, query, recursão

Possuo conhecimentos básicos de banco de dados e de MySQL, gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar a diminuir o 'tamanho' de uma query e sua redundância (facilitando a manutenção futura).

Trata-se de um relatório financeiro com hierarquia de até 5 níveis, sendo a conta superior uma totalizadora da conta de nível inferior, sucessivamente. Para alcançar este objetivo fiz um UNION de alguns SELECTs, ficando, portanto, bem redundante.

Exemplo :

[image: Tabelas]

Queries:

A primeira query seleciona os saldos para cada conta de nível 4 da hierarquia, depois eu uso essa base na cláusula from da query seguinte para oobter as contas de nível 3 e assim por diante:

MySql

```
 -- base de contas de nível 4
Select  
L.Data, 
H.Conta, 
L.Valor 
From  
lançamentos L 
Inner join  categorias C on C.Categoria = L.categoria 
Inner join hierarquia_de_categorias H on H.conta=C.Hierarquia 

UNION 

-- base de contas de nível 3 Select 
N3.Data,
N3.Conta,
N3.Valor
From 
( -- base de contas de nível 4
Select L.Data, H.Conta, L.Valor From  lançamentos L Inner join categorias C on C.Categoria = L.categoria Inner join hierarquia_de_categorias H on H.conta=C.Hierarquia) n3

UNION
-- base de contas de nível 2 
Select 
N2.Data, 
N2.Conta,
N2.Valor
From 
(
(-- base de contas de nível 3 Select N3.Data, N3.Conta, N3.Valor From ( -- base de contas de nível 4 Select L.Data, H.Conta, L.Valor From  lançamentos L Inner join categorias C on C.Categoria = L.categoria Inner join hierarquia_de_categorias H on H.conta=C.Hierarquia) n3
) n2
 
UNION

-- base de contas de nível 1
Select 
N1.Data,
N1.Conta,
N1.Valor
From
(-- base de contas de nível 2 Select N2.Data, N2.Conta, N2.Valor From ((-- base de contas de nível 3 Select N3.Data, N3.Conta, N3.Valor From ( -- base de contas de nível 4 Select L.Data, H.Conta, L.Valor From  lançamentos L Inner join categorias C on C.Categoria = L.categoria Inner join hierarquia_de_categorias H on H.conta=C.Hierarquia) n3 ) n2 
) n1
```

Resultado :

[image: Resultado]